# Perl как сгенерировать таблицу?

Tags: cgi, perl

можно ли как то генерировать таблицы, если указать сколько столбцов должно быть.
к примеру, берем 50 картинок из базы, загоняем в масив, указуем по 10 в ширину, а дальше генерируется таблица.

что то не могу придумать как с помощью CGI разбить на ряды.

```
print table(
    Tr(td(\@foto)),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@values = (1..50);
@headings = ('A' .. 'J');
@rows = CGI::th(\@headings);
foreach $n (@values) { push(@rows,CGI::td(gl(splice(@values, 0, 10)))) }
print CGI::table({-border=>undef,-width=>'25%'},
  CGI::caption(CGI::b('Wow. I can!')),
  CGI::Tr(\@rows)
);

sub gl {
    return \@_;
}
```

Comment: класно, а попроще?

Answer (score 1):

спасибо, 2Roman.
поковыряв, сделал коротко и понятно (как для меня)

```
@values = (1..50);
for (1 .. @values/10) {
    @row = splice(@values, 0, 10);
    push @rows,CGI::td(\@row);
}
print CGI::table({-border=>undef,-width=>'25%'},
    CGI::Tr(\@rows)
);
```